# Get URL from UIImage Swift

Tags: ios, swift, url, uiimage

If it's possible I need to get the Url of the photo that I upload after this functions:

```
@IBAction func ButtonScatta(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

@IBAction func ButtonScegli(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]!) {
    ImageView.image = image
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

I also need to convert the Url into a String

Comment: the URL of the photo on the device (in the camera roll) or the URL of the photo that you uploaded to a remote machine?

Comment: Neither is available...

Comment: @MichaelDautermann the URL of the photo on the device and the url of the photo that I take